# Simplify Kunneth formula by universal coefficient theorem, in the bottom of p276 of Hatcher

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

> Theorem3A.3. If $C$ is a chain complex of free abelian groups, then there are natural
> short exact sequences
> $0 →H_n(C;\mathbb Z)⊗G →H_n(C;G) →Tor(H_{n−1}(C;\mathbb Z),G) →0$
> for all n and all G, and these sequences split, though not naturally.

> Theorem 3B.6. If $X$ and $Y$ are CW complexes and $R$ is a principal ideal domain,
> then there are natural short exact sequences
> $0\to \bigoplus_i
> H_i(X;R)⊗_R H_{n−i}(Y;R)→H_n(X×Y;R) →\bigoplus_i Tor_R(H_i(X;R),H_{n−i−1}(Y;R))→0$
> and these sequences split.

In the bottom of p276 of Hatcher, he used the splitting of the above two sequences to obtain

$H_n(X×Y;R)\approx\bigoplus_i H_i(X;H_{n-i}(Y;R))\qquad      (*)$.

But I can only get the following isomorphisms:

\begin{align}
H_i(X;H_{n-i}(Y;R))&\approx H_i(X;\mathbb Z)⊗ H_{n−i}(Y;R) \oplus Tor(H_{i-1}(X;\mathbb Z),H_{n−i}(Y;R))\\[10 pt]
H_n(X×Y;R)&\approx\bigoplus_i
H_i(X;R)⊗_R H_{n−i}(Y;R) \oplus \bigoplus_i Tor_R(H_i(X;R),H_{n−i−1}(Y;R))
\end{align}

It seems that we get $(*)$ if
\begin{align}
H_i(X;\mathbb Z)⊗ H_{n−i}(Y;R) &\approx H_i(X;R)⊗_R H_{n−i}(Y;R)\\[10pt]
Tor(H_{i}(X;\mathbb Z),H_{n}(Y;R))&\approx Tor_R(H_i(X;R),H_{n−i−1}(Y;R)).
\end{align}

Are the above two isomorphisms exist? what are they? Maybe they are well-known facts about the tensor product, but I lack knowledge of algebra...

Thank you.

Comment: Try writing down what happens when $n=2$, for example: write down all of the terms in your big direct sum expression (using Künneth) for $H_2(X \times Y)$ and also write down each term (using the universal coefficient theorem) $H_i(X; H_{2-i}(Y))$ for $i=0,1,2$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a counterexample for your first isomorphism, but I could be missing something (please let me know if that's the case). It seems like you're trying to use the following formula:
$$
H_i(X;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes G \cong H_i(X;R) \otimes_R G\tag1
$$
where $G$ is an abelian group. Now on p. 215 Hatcher states that $A \otimes B = A \otimes_R B$ if $R=\mathbb{Z}/m$. So let's consider $R=\mathbb{Z}/2$ for instance. Take some odd positive integer $n$. Then $H_n(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_n(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb{Z}/2) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$. It follows that
$$
H_n(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/2} G \cong \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/2} G \quad\text{and}\quad  H_n(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb{Z}/2) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/2} G \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/2} G \cong G.
$$
But if we choose $G = \mathbb{Z}/2$ we see that these two expressions are not isomorphic, so $(1)$ cannot be true. I hope this is helpful!